# Can we add optional chaining in .classlist for null checking in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6, frontend

can we use optional chaining, i.e "?." for null checking ...

```
$(.class)?.get(0)?.classList.add('hidden);
```

because am, getting errors like "Cannot read properties of undefined( reading 'classList') when .class is not availble

Comment: You shouldn't need to when using jQuery methods, but I don't see why you can't after `.get(0)`.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you using `classList` in the first place? You don't need to do any null checking on jQuery objects if you use jQuery methods as it handles that case for you. This is one of the largest benefits of using jQuery. `$('.class').addClass('hidden');`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: so if i use addClass, then it will by default check if ".class" exist or not, then it will apply hidden??

Comment: `$(".class").addClass("hidden")` will add hidden class to all elements (or none if there aren't any) with class "class".   There's no need to check if `$(".class")` finds any elements.

Comment: `jQuery(".class")[0].classList` (without `?.`) will give you `cannot read properties of undefined reading classList` - but with `?.` you just get `undefined`  - `$(".class").get(0)?.classList.add("hidden")` does nothing (if no elements with class).  So if you're getting "cannot read properties of undefined" then you're missing a `?` somewhere along the line.

Comment: can i use like this $(".class").get(0).addClass("hidden")

Comment: `$('.class').eq(0).addClass('hidden')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to use is to use like this:

```
$('.class').get(0).addClass('hidden')
```

Answer (score -2):

first of all there no need to check if .class exists, but just for the sake of code you can try this:

```
 if($(".class").length >0){
  $(this).addClass("hidden");
  }
```

Comment: `this` is not the same as `$(".class")`